# Python Flask server отключение вывода в консоль для одной функции

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flask

Flask по умолчанию все запросы пишет в консоль, это хорошо, но у меня есть одна echo функция на сайте, которая на js вызывается каждую секунду, из-за которой засорятся вывод.

Вопрос такой, как отключить вывод в консоль, только на одну функцию?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62000942/flask-block-specific-endpoints-from-logging

Answer (score 1):

Решил таким способом

```
from flask.logging import logging
class echo_filter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        try:
            if record.args[0].find('def_name') != -1: return False
            else: return True
        except:
            return True
logging.getLogger("werkzeug").addFilter(echo_filter())
```

Answer (score 0):

Либо переопределите вызываемую функцию - изменив ее под себя, либо напишите аналогичную поставив в ней условие проверки. Самое элементарное:

```
def printF(value, flag=False):
    if flag:
        print(value)

printF(value=345) # Печатать выражение не будет
printF(333, True) # Печатать выражение будет
```

Comment: Это не ТС печатает запросы. Это сам Flask печатает входящий запрос. Вопрос в том как сконфигурировать Flask так чтобы часть запросов не попадала в лог.